# Is it ok to simply change the PayPal Express API version number?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm dealing with a shopping cart system that doesn't really stay updated with the changes to PayPal's API.  I have the source code and am confident enough to add/change parameters for calls (e.g. for expresscheckout) -- but some of the things I want to do are only available in newer versions of the API.

The cart PayPal PHP code sets the PayPal API version to '76' right now.

Can I safely just change it to '112' - or do I have to carefully audit and test all the existing code?  In other words, is it safe to assume that PayPal's newer API versions are backward compatible with older code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade the API version to [**113**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_Release_Notes_113/) and yes it is backward compatible and supports all existing parameters.

Note : Check this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) to see the deprecated parameters that should be avoided.